# Convert dtype= object to dtype='|S5'

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas, scikit-learn

l have a csv file that l load with pandas as follow:

```
classes_dataset2=pd.read_csv("labels.csv")
classes_dataset2[0:10]

0    A
1    A
2    N
3    N
4    O
5    O
6    5
7    5
8    P
9    P
Name: label, dtype: object
```

This  `dtype: object` is not accepted when

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
encoder=LabelBinarizer()
classes_dataset = encoder.fit_transform(classes_dataset2)
```

l got the following error

```
ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)
```

This why l want to transform `dtype` from object to `dtype='|S5'` so that to get my labels as follow :

```
array(['A', 'A', 'N', 'N', 'O', 'O', '5', '5', 'P', 'P'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

How can l transform object type to '|S5' type ?

**EDIT1**

When l do `classes_dataset2.astype('|S5')`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
encoder=LabelBinarizer()
classes_dataset = encoder.fit_transform(classes_dataset2.astype('|S5'))
```

l get no error. it seems that it works. However , l'm wondering if it takes

['A','A','N','N','O','O','5','5,'P','P'] or 
[0,1,2,.. 9] ?
can you confirm to me that it takes :
['A','A','N','N','O','O','5','5,'P','P']  and not the indexes ?

Comment: does `classes_dataset2.astype(str)` work?

Comment: yes it works  but it prints 0    A
1    A
2    N
3    N
4    O
5    O
6    5
7    5
8    P
9    P
Name: label, dtype: object

Comment: `object` just means python object, the actual element dtypes are `str`, this is expected behaviour

Comment: indeed, yes. But l need my data in '|S5' for the reason l explained

Comment: You can do `classes_dateset2.astype('|S5')`

Comment: @EdChum, please see my update it seems to work. Can you confirm ?

Comment: It converts the elements not the index, you'd have to do `classes_dateset2.index.astype('|S5')` to modify the index

Comment: classes_dataset = encoder.fit_transform(classes_dataset2.astype('|S5')) this what l've done

Comment: So does it work? it's pointless to ask me as I don't have your data or code

Comment: Yes it wokrs. l don't get any more the error

Comment: Do you want me to post an answer now we're happy?

Comment: yes for sure please do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `astype` to cast the `dtype` of the `Series`, generally I'd go for `str` but if you insist on the numpy type `'|S5'` then you can just pass this:

```
In [16]:    
s = pd.Series(['A','A', 'N', 'N', 'O', 'O', 5, 5, 'P','P'])
s

Out[16]:
0    A
1    A
2    N
3    N
4    O
5    O
6    5
7    5
8    P
9    P
dtype: object    

In [18]:
s.astype('|S5')

Out[18]:
0    b'A'
1    b'A'
2    b'N'
3    b'N'
4    b'O'
5    b'O'
6    b'5'
7    b'5'
8    b'P'
9    b'P'
dtype: bytes40
```

Referring to what `object` means here, if you have mixed dtypes that are not all numerical or are `str` then `object` here refers to python object which is the expected and correct behaviour